# Windows Explorer Folder Groups Toggle Collapse

Tags: windows-explorer, hotkeys

Is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut for "Expand All Groups / Collapse All Groups" in Windows 7 Explorer?  In Explorer their is not a shortcut listed.  Does one already exist that I haven't seen?

By the way, I've searched high and low and I can't find a matching question to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, but hilariously enough you can repeatedly tap the left arrow, then down arrow to go through and collapse all the groups. Left arrow to collapse the group, and down to go to the next group. You could also use the right arrow to expand all group. It's kinda dumb but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Use the <kbd>*</kbd> key to expand all and the <kbd>-</kbd> key to collapse all.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on a grouping and select collapse or expand all from the context menu.[image]